# Alert invoked in React JS componentDidMount lifecycle method pops up before the initial render instead of after

Tags: javascript, reactjs, alert, lifecycle

I'm going through the Codecademy React JS course: https://www.codecademy.com/courses/react-102/lessons/mounting-lifecycle-methods/exercises/componentdidmount

The lesson explains the basics of the React lifecycle mounting methods ordering them as follows: componentWillMount -> render -> componentDidMount.

This codepen demonstrates the problem: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/vXyYKP

The issue is that according to the instructions the **alert included in the `componentDidMount` method** (saying: 'YOU JUST WITNESSED THE DEBUT OF...  FLASHY!!!!!!!') **should pop up after** the red text is rendered on the screen. However when I test it, the alert **actually pops up before** the text is rendered. Is this the expected behaviour?

Full code:

```
var Flashy = React.createClass({
  componentWillMount: function() {
    alert('AND NOW, FOR THE FIRST TIME EVER...  FLASHY!!!!');
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    alert('YOU JUST WITNESSED THE DEBUT OF...  FLASHY!!!!!!!');
  },

  render: function() {
    alert('Flashy is rendering!');
    return (
      <h1 style={{ color: this.props.color }}>
        OOH LA LA LOOK AT ME I AM THE FLASHIEST
      </h1>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Flashy color='red' />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);

setTimeout(function() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Flashy color='green' />,
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually working as expected.

But the `alert` function prevents the DOM rendering

You can actually try it with `console.log` which works in the background.

Take a look of this codepen http://codepen.io/joseaplwork/pen/xERkaG

Make sure to open the inspector, I also added a debugger statement in order to see when `componentDidMount` is called

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you. Do you know why the DOM render is blocked by the alert in `componentDidMount`? Isn't it invoked after the render is finished?`